# WordPress admin panel not working

Tags: plugin-development, themes, wp-admin, wp-error

Today I added all the codes to the new server and I am getting the issue like the below image. WordPress admin panel not working.

[image]

I tried below code `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);`  then I am getting the CSS and admin panel is also looking same but If I click on any link then I am getting below error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you access the file(s) where you have added the new code and remove locally or directly via the cpanel. Then continue to add this code or plugin back one-by-one to see what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Same code working on another hosting but not working on GoDaddy. Give me some time I'll try your answer